# Win10 "explorer.exe Incorrect function." at every startup

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I am on Win10 and since today at EVERY startup this error message (explorer.exe "Incorrect function.") pops up and its quiet annoying... [Screenshot of Error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phpzq.png)

I already tried looking in the eventviewer under event id 1000 but it only shows an error with the searchapp.exe wich I think is unrelated and has only happened once and not at every startup.
I also "upgraded" my windows with the mediacreation tool and kept applications and personal files to fix the problem but it didn't help.

I hope some of you might be able to help me fix it...
I can't even find someone on Google with the same problem...

**EDIT:**

In safe mode the error doesn't occur but I don't really know what to do with this information

I also tried disabling Shell Extensions with ShellExView and Autoruns but it didn't help...

Comment: I almost guarantee that this is the result of a third party shell extension.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Do you have any idea how to fix it though... already tried with shellexview and autoruns...

Comment: Nope.. sorry.. you already did what I would have done.  Let me think about it.

Comment: The biggest problem here is that error is completely nondescript.  It is error #1 ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION and could mean anything.  It is usually related to file system and or file system drivers.  I can see that most programmers that encounter it do so when calling one of the file system functions like `CreateFile()` `OpenFile()` `FindFirstFile()` and the like.. I will keep looking...